# Spring Boot/Hibernate/MySQL is not working

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying to build web application with Spring Boot/Hibernate/MySQL but I have an exceptoin running it:

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> Tue Oct 25 16:05:16 EEST 2016 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404).

Can someone tell my what am I doing wrong?
My sources:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SpringBootWebApplication{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MVCconfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

poom.file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>lardi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Phone Book</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <start-class>com.SpringBootWebApplication</start-class>

        <!-- JSON -->
        <jackson-json.version>2.8.0</jackson-json.version>

        <!-- WEB jars -->
        <webjars-bootstrap.version>3.3.6</webjars-bootstrap.version>
        <webjars-jquery.version>2.2.4</webjars-jquery.version>
        <webjars-noty.version>2.3.8</webjars-noty.version>
        <webjars-datatables.version>1.10.12</webjars-datatables.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot WEB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot TEST -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-json.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-json.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-json.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Webjars -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-jquery.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>noty</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-noty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatables</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-datatables.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Spring authentication disable:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()


     .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();

}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class RootController extends AbstractContactController{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String root() {
        return "redirect:contacts";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/contacts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String contactList() {
        return "contactList";
    }
}
```

And .jsp file

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
        Hello!
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to open /contacts directly without redirect? The error you get says for some reason your http request could not be mapped to your RequestMapping methods.

Comment: Firstly, change return "redirect:contacts";  to  return "redirect:/contacts";
You can simply add logger inside requested methods to check if it works.
And please read aswell this part of docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content
It is not recommended to use jsp files in spring boot.

Comment: Do you have more then one request mapping to "/error"?

Comment: I tryed everything but still have the same exception. I thing my root controller does not want to get requests but I do not know why. Can somebody tell me?

Answer (score 0):

please see method configureViewResolvers, I think it solve your error and also see all the things I have done in class and use it in your getViewResolver:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/admin/home").setViewName("jsp/home");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**", "/img/**", "/css/**", "/pages/**", "/js/**").addResourceLocations(
                "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/", "classpath:/static/img/", "classpath:/static/css/",
                "classpath:/static/pages/", "classpath:/static/js/");
    }

    @Bean
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
```